# Protecting a route using Firebase Simple Login

Tags: ember.js, firebase, emberfire

I'm trying to implement the following sequence of events in an Ember app that uses Firebase Simple Login and `ember-cli`.

1. Check if the user is authenticated before allowing entry to any route. *All* routes need to be authenticated.
2. If the user is not authenticated, redirect to `LoginRoute`. If the user is authenticated, allow them to enter the route.

In order to accomplish step 1, I reopen `Ember.Route` in an initializer and implement a `beforeModel` hook.

```
`import LoginController from "tracking/controllers/login"`

AuthInitializer =
  name: 'authInitializer'

  initialize: (container, application) ->
    # Register LoginController with all controllers/routes
    application.register 'main:auth', LoginController
    application.inject 'route', 'auth', 'main:auth'
    application.inject 'controller', 'auth', 'main:auth'
    application.inject 'main:auth', 'store', 'store:main'

    # Ensure user is logged in before allowing entry
    Ember.Route.reopen
      beforeModel: (transition) ->
        @transitionTo 'login' if !@get('auth.isAuthed')

`export default AuthInitializer`
```

The above code does indeed redirect to `login` if the user is not currently logged in.

`LoginController` simply instantiates a new `FirebaseSimpleLogin` object and registers the appropriate callback function.

```
LoginController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  # Some of the controller is omitted for brevity...

  auth: null
  isAuthed: false

  init: ->
    dbRef = new Firebase('https://dawnbreaker.firebaseio.com')
    @set('auth', new FirebaseSimpleLogin(dbRef, @authCompleted.bind(@)))
    @_super()

  authCompleted: (error, user) ->
    if error
      # Handle invalid login attempt..
    else if user
      # Handle successful login..
      unless @get('isAuthed')
        @set('currentUserId', user.id)
        @set('isAuthed', true)
        @transitionToRoute('index')
    else
      # Handle logout..
      @set('currentUserId', null)
      @set('isAuthed', false)

`export default LoginController`
```

There is two problems with my implementation.

- When `LoginController` first initializes, `isAuthed` is set to false. Therefore, when `authCompleted` finishes, the app will *always* redirect to `index`.
- The `beforeModel` hook executes *before* the `authCompleted` callback finishes, causing the hook to redirect to `login`.

What results from a page refresh is

1. The `login` template flashes for a second.
2. The app transitions to `index`.

This causes *every* page refresh to lose its current location (redirecting to the `index` route).

**The question is,** how can I protect a route using Ember and Firebase Simple Login? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Totally my opinion, but I like making the auth part of the resource tree.  It doesn't need to be part of the url, but can be.  Using this way, it can still use a global controller (it will be hooked up based on what's returned from the call, or some other hookup if you fetch it in the login).

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('auth', {path:''}, function(){
    this.resource('foo');
    this.resource('bar', function(){
      this.route('baz')
    });
  });
  this.route('login');
});

App.AuthRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(params, transition){
    var self = this;
    // you can skip calling back with a local property
    return $.getJSON('/auth').then(function(result){
      if(!result.good){
        self.transitionTo('login');
      }
      return result;
    });
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/668/edit

In the case of a non-promise callback, you can create your own promise, and resolve that when appropriate.

```
model: function(){
  var defer = Ember.RSVP.defer(),
      firebase = new Firebase('https://dawnbreaker.firebaseio.com'),
      fbLogin = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(firebase, this.authCompleted.bind(this));


  this.setProperties({
      defer: defer, 
      firebase: firebase,
      fbLogin: fbLogin
  });

  return defer.promise.then(function(result){
    // maybe redirect if authed etc...
  });
},
authCompleted: function(error, user){
  var defer = this.get('defer');
  //if authenticated
  defer.resolve({auth:true});      
  //else authenticated
  defer.resolve({auth:false});      
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna try and flesh something out using this solution. I think there might still be an issue because of Firebase's callback approach with their Simple Login. Any quick thoughts on that?

Comment: Tossed up an example of how to create your own promise/deferred

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed example using Firebase. I ended up using this approach.